# Writing Hexadecimal and Binary Values to File

Tags: java, clojure, binary, hex

How can I write hexadecimal and binary values (not their string representation) to a file? For example, how can I write the hexadecimal value 1A (26 in decimal) to a file?

Previously, I've tried using a BufferedWriter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(ns test.core
  (:use [clojure.java.io]))

(with-open [os (output-stream "/tmp/foo")]
  (.write os 0x1A))
```

Note that the `with-open` macro is quite handy when dealing with I/O.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using an `OutputStream` for writing binary data rather than a `Writer` implementation (which is appropriate for text data).

**Java Example**

(Sorry I don't know Clojure)

```
byte b = 0x1A;
OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("c:\tmp\out.dat"));
os.write(b);
```